# Intuition behind limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I understand the concept of a limit, but here is my problem. Say I want to find the limit of some function $f(x)$ as $x\to0$. What checks/list should I go through to make sure the limit will exist? Is there an intuitive way to check if the limit will exist without having to check both left and right-hand limits? Based on my understanding, I would always have to check $x\to 0^-$ and $x\to 0^+$. However, with some limits, this is not necessary and we can just "plug-in", say for this example, $0$. I noticed in cases where we can just plug-in, $f(x)$ would have been in the form "$0/0$", requiring me to do some algebra to find the limit. In cases where, but is not restricted to, the limit as $x\to 0$ does not exist, $f(x)$ is in the form "$n/0$" where $n$ is some number other than $0$.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard (if not impossible) to capture "all cases" in a few simple guidelines, but based on your question I'll *limit* (pun not intended!) this answer to the most common things you'll encounter when taking a limit $x \to a$, where $a$ can be $0$ but not necessarily, of a function in the form of a fraction $\tfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. So you're looking at a limit of the form:
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
When you would simply plug in $x=a$, there are four cases regarding $0$ that can arise:

1. $\frac{\mbox{non-zero}}{\mbox{non-zero}}$: there is no problem...!
2. $\frac{\mbox{zero}}{\mbox{non-zero}}$: again, there is no problem: the fraction is simply $0$.
3. $\frac{\mbox{non-zero}}{\mbox{zero}}$: in absolute value, the fraction will tend to $\infty$; check the right- and left-handed limits to see whether these are $\pm \infty$ (and they can have the same or a different sign).
4. $\frac{\mbox{zero}}{\mbox{zero}}$: anything can happen here, further investigation is necessary.

In this last case, you'll typically try to eliminate the indeterminate form "$\tfrac{0}{0}$" by:

- factoring and canceling $x-a$ when possible, e.g. when $f$ and $g$ are polynomials;
- multiplying numerator and denominator with a suitable conjugate expression to get rid of (square or other) roots; again trying to cancel a factor of the form $x-a$ afterwards;
- using standard limits such as $\tfrac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$;
- using techniques such as l'Hôpital's rule or (pieces of) Taylor series.

Note that this is a simplified overview (incomplete and not rigorous) but it probably covers most of the simple examples you encounter when you're new to calculating limits. Questions? Shoot!

---

### Examples

I'll add an example for each of the four categories.

1. Consider the following limit:
   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{3x+4}}{x^2-3}$$
   Plugging in shows there's no problem in numerator nor denominator; the function is continuous in $x=0$ and you simply find the limit as:
   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{3x+4}}{x^2-3}=\frac{\sqrt{3\cdot 0+4}}{0^2-3}=\frac{\sqrt{4}}{-3} = -\frac{2}{3}$$
2. Next up, one where only the numerator becomes $0$:
   $$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x^2-4}{\sqrt{3-x}}=\frac{(-2)^2-4}{\sqrt{3-(-2)}}=\frac{0}{\sqrt{5}}  = 0$$
3. Only the denominator tends to $0$:
   $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2x}{x-1}$$
   Now notice that near $x=1$, the numerator is positive and the denominator is positive for $x>1$ but negative for $x<1$; hence:
   $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{2x}{x-1} = +\infty \quad\mbox{and}\quad \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{2x}{x-1} = -\infty \implies \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2x}{x-1} \;\mbox{"does not exist"}$$
   Note that with a square in the denominator, we would have:
   $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{2x}{\left( x-1 \right)^2} = +\infty \quad\mbox{and}\quad \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{2x}{\left( x-1 \right)^2} = +\infty \implies \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2x}{\left( x-1 \right)^2}  = +\infty$$
4. Plugging in gives the indeterminate form "$\tfrac{0}{0}$":
   $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x^2-2x}$$
   Factoring, canceling and trying again:
   $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x^2-2x} = 
   \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\color{red}{(x-2)}(x+2)}{x\color{red}{(x-2)}}= 
   \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x+2}{x} = \frac{2+2}{2}=2$$

Comment: Coming at you with another question! Suppose I have f(x) = (x-3)/(x^2 - 4) and I take the limit as x->2. This limit does not exist. Question: Would I be forced, with functions similar to this, to look at the left and right-hand limits in order to check?

Comment: @darylnak I was still adding examples; perhaps the example at number 3 helps with this particular question? Note that around 2 your numerator is positive but the sign of the denominator depends on which side of 2 you're coming from.

Comment: From my understanding, as is the fact with most mathematical subjects I've taken thus far, the approach is on a case-by-case basis. If so, I better do more problems!